# Windows 7 Outbound PPTP Connections

Tags: windows, windows-7, pptp

I have various locations that I connect to using Windows 7 PPTP outbound connections.  I'm able to make any 2 connections, but the third connection fails.  I was wondering if anyone knew of a registry change that would allow more connections.  If not, could I run these PPTP connections on a server and share them to the workstations?  If so, provide details as I have attempted this in the past and failed.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Without a network diagram I'm shooting from the hip...if you have multiple hosts at the same site that need to access the same remote resources does it make sense to use a VPN appliance/firewall to tunnel?  That seems like a more reliable and less troublesome way to do it.  Windows 7 will only allow two concurrent VPN tunnels of the same type, as you know.  Windows Server allows more (unlimited?)